# Problema na condição do trigger - PL-SQL

Tags: pl-sql, sqldeveloper

Meu professor passou essa questão:

Escreva um trigger que verifique, durante o cadastro/alteração de uma venda, o seguinte:

1) O campo QUANTIDADE da tabela ITEMVENDA não pode ter casas decimais e deve ser maior ou igual a 1;

2) O campo VALOR da tabela ITEMVENDA deve ser maior que 0.

Quando as condições acima não forem atendidas, a transação deverá ser cancelada e uma das seguintes mensagens
de erro deverá ser exibida, respectivamente:

1) “A quantidade do produto não pode ser fracionada e deve ser maior ou igual a 1”;

2) “O valor do produto deve ser maior que 0”.

Aí fiz o código:

```
    CREATE OR replace TRIGGER especificacoes
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON itemvenda 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  WHEN (new.quantidade <> round(new.quantidade) OR (new.quantidade < 1) OR (new.valor < 1)) 
BEGIN 
 IF (:new.quantidade <> round(:new.quantidade)) OR (:new.quantidade < 1)
 THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'“A quantidade do produto não pode ser fracionada e deve ser maior ou igual a 1”; ');
 END IF;

 IF (:new.valor < 1 )
 THEN
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20022,'“O valor do produto deve ser maior que 0”.');
 END IF;
END;
```

O SQL Developer compilou normalmente e fiz alguns testes (UPDATE E INSERT), as condições relacionadas a coluna quantidade não estão funcionando. Teoricamente, deveria aparecer: “A quantidade do produto não pode ser fracionada e deve ser maior ou igual a 1” e bloquear a operação.

Esse aqui é o erro que aparece quando tem uma operação errada na coluna valor:

"UPDATE "SYSTEM"."ITEMVENDA" SET VALOR = '0' WHERE ROWID = 'AAASNqAABAAAaGxAAE' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '2140564'
ORA-20022: “O valor do produto deve ser maior que 0”.
ORA-06512: em "SYSTEM.ESPECIFICACOES", line 9
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'SYSTEM.ESPECIFICACOES'

Ocorreu um erro ao salvar alterações na tabela "SYSTEM"."ITEMVENDA":
Linha 5: ORA-20022: “O valor do produto deve ser maior que 0”.
ORA-06512: em "SYSTEM.ESPECIFICACOES", line 9
ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do gatilho 'SYSTEM.ESPECIFICACOES'"

Não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro, será que esse round está quebrando a condição da coluna quantidade?.

Comment: Não entendi , foi feito um update ou insert para a quantidade ?

Comment: Fiz e ele aceitou normalmente.

Comment: Teoricamente, deveria aparecer: “A quantidade do produto não pode ser fracionada e deve ser maior ou igual a 1” e bloquear a operação.

Comment: Edita o post e publica.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta do professor:

O único problema que existe em seu código é no uso de aspas duplas no RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.  Ao invés de ser assim:
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'“A quantidade do produto não pode ser fracionada e deve ser maior ou igual a 1”; ');

tem que ser assim:
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20010,'A quantidade do produto não pode ser fracionada e deve ser maior ou igual a 1.');

Com relação a sua lógica, não há nenhum erro.  Quando se tenta colocar o campo QUANTIDADE da tabela ITEMVENDA com valor fracionado (ex.: 4.7) o Oracle arredonda ele automaticamente, pois na tabela ele foi declarado como NUMBER(5) - sem parte decimal.

Se o campo QUANTIDADE na tabela ITEMVENDA for alterado para NUMBER(6,1), começará a exibir a mensagem para valores fracionados que você programou.